# Joomla module. Unable to install language .ini files properly

Tags: joomla, module, joomla3.0, joomla3.2

I made a very simple joomla 3.2 module, but i can not manage to install my language `.ini` and `sys.ini` files.

Part of my .xml file

```
<files>
    <filename>mod_myModuleTitle.xml</filename>
    <filename module="mod_myModuleTitle">mod_myModuleTitle.php</filename>
    <filename>index.html</filename>
    <filename>helper.php</filename>
    <folder>lib</folder>
    <folder>tmpl</folder>
</files>

<languages folder="language">
    <language tag="en-GB">en-GB/en-GB.mod_myModuleTitle.ini></language>
    <language tag="en-GB">en-GB/en-GB.mod_myModuleTitle.sys.ini></language>
    <language tag="it-IT">it-IT/it-IT.mod_myModuleTitle.ini></language>
    <language tag="it-IT">it-IT/it-IT.mod_myModuleTitle.sys.ini></language>
</languages>
```

the ini files are inside **myModuleTitle/language/en-GB folder** and **myModuleTitle/language/it-IT** folder

Trying installing I got:

```
Warning JInstaller: :Install: File does not exist path/to/my/local/web/server/tmp/mod_myModuleTitle/language/en-GB/en-GB.mod_myModuleTitle.ini
```

EDIT
SOLVED!!!

adding tag

```
<folder>language</folder>
```

and removing

```
<languages folder="language">
    <language tag="en-GB">en-GB/en-GB.mod_myModuleTitle.ini></language>
    <language tag="en-GB">en-GB/en-GB.mod_myModuleTitle.sys.ini></language>
    <language tag="it-IT">it-IT/it-IT.mod_myModuleTitle.ini></language>
    <language tag="it-IT">it-IT/it-IT.mod_myModuleTitle.sys.ini></language>
</languages>
```

solved my problem, languages .ini files are installed and used correctly.

Comment: is the `tmp` folder in your Joomla site writable? If not set the permissions to 755

Comment: yes, all is writable... 777

Comment: 777? even though this makes it writable, change it back to 755 for security reasons

Comment: adding another tag folder "language", ini files will be copied, but error persists

Answer (score 0):

Glad you worked it out, for others looking at this question, the `<language>` element was **deprecated** in Joomla 1.6, the recommended approach since then has been for *all* language files (normal and system) to be stored with the extension.

You can read more about it in [Language section](http://docs.joomla.org/Manifest_files#Language_files) of the [Manfest files](http://docs.joomla.org/Manifest_files) article on the [Joomla Doc's](http://docs.joomla.org/) site.

Comment: I had no idea that it had been deprecated. I assume they  haven't actually removed it for Joomla 3.2 as it still works. But thanks for the info :)

Comment: Just as an additional info: Joomla will first try to load the language file from the /languages/ folder and if not found it will go to /your_extension/languages/.
This allows to override languages files by putting them in the global /languages/ folder. This is one reason why you should have the files within your extension.
The other reason is that the files put in the global folder only stay there if the language is installed. Which means if you install the module and only afterwards install the italian languagepack, the files would not be there.